# How to use invoke-wmimethod without specifying an argument?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to create a PowerShell command that edits some information of a shared folder. There are 3 arguments access, description and max users but I only want to change description and max users.

I need this code to work on Windows 2008 and more current versions.

These commands work to change the parameters of a shared folder:

```
$c = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Share WHERE Name=`'ADMIN`$`'";

Invoke-WmiMethod -InputObject $c -Name SetShareInfo -ArgumentList @($null,"Remote Admin","5")
```

But in the process I believe it will delete the access parameter.

Does anyone know an easy way to edit a shared folder's parameters.

Comment: Your code did not appear to wipe out any access I have set up on my share. I don't know of an "easy" way to manage shares in PowerShell v2.

Comment: `Invoke-WmiMethod` requires arguments to be passed to methods that require them. I don't know that there is any way around that besides just using another command. If you don't like where you have to provide the arguments, you can create a function that will then pass parameter values into the `Invoke-WmiMethod`. That does add some flexibility. PowerShell v2 has serious limitations compared to v3 and newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would work with the method this way.  You can double check the order of the arguments.

```
$a = get-wmiobject win32_share | where name -eq admin$
$a.setshareinfo

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Management.ManagementBaseObject SetShareInfo(System.UInt32 MaximumAllowed,System.String Description, System.Management.ManagementObject#Win32_SecurityDescriptor Access)

$a.setshareinfo($null,'Remote Admin','5')
```